# Shortest distance between two vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

In the graph, we have to find the shortest distance between Newark and Cape May. I have tried using the Dijkstra algorithm but I can't seem to figure out how it would work. According to my working, the distance is coming out to be 175 whereas it should be 85.

[image: graph]

Comment: you could get 165 with that graph, but 85 doesn't seem possible (go to Camden from Woodbridge) (and, do you mean 85 or 185?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Djikstra's algorithm gives Newark-Woodbridge-Camden-Cape May with a distance of $165$.

I suspect that your error was to permanently box Atlantic City (on $130$) before you had boxed Camden (on $80$).

Answer (score 0):

$85$ does not make sense: from Cape May you could only reach Camden and Atlantic City.

[image]